# Jenkins CI Custom Test File

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to run nightwatch tests on several components of my web app.

I've also written another file (Lets say it's called "customTest.js") that I run with  right after my nightwatch tests pass.

`node customTest.js`

This is basically a final test of the data the web app downloads.

What I would like to happen, is if a conditional statement in my customTest.js file returns a certain value, I fail the jenkins test, exactly as nightwatch would fail a test, and if it doesn't return that value, then it passes on to the next post-build steps etc.

Any thoughts on whether this is possible and how it can be implemented.